# Lost in debugging a flex project

Tags: debugging, flex3, flexbuilder

I'm OK with debugging .as files,but when it comes across .mxml files,I feel really lost.

It's not tracing in a traditional way ,line by line...

How to get started with debugging such files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add break points in the MXML. Like you can in with ActionScript.